# How to divide data from different index with gnuplot?

Tags: indexing, gnuplot

I've not found any way to do that (maybe because there is none?):
I've got a different set of data such as :

#index 1

```
1 4  
2 8  
3 12  
4 16  
5 20
```

#index 2

```
1 1  
2 4  
3 9  
4 16  
5 25
```

And I'd like to do something like that :
plot using `1:($(index1:2)/$(index2:2))`

i.e. Dividing the value of the first set of the second set (to normalize)

Is there any way to do that with gnuplot?

Comment: You can't do that in gnuplot, you need an external tool to do this kind of data processing. Inside gnuplot you can extract only some information like the average, maximum or minimum values of a data block using the `stats` command (since 4.6.0).

Answer (score 0):

I can't do it in gnuplot level. Try to use `join` unix command.